# Having trouble printing the results of my query

Tags: python, sql

```
query = c.execute('SELECT * FROM Patients')

resultset = c.fetchall()

if not resultset:
    print("Sorry, the last name you entered does not match any patients "
          "in the hospital.") #if there are no results this is printed
else:
    for result in resultset:
        result = ' '.join(result)
        print("\n\t", result)
```

I saw a suggestion that said to change it to ','.join([None])  but I tried it and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have created a cursor object:

```
c = sqlite3.connect('databasename.db').cursor()
query = list(c.execute('SELECT * FROM Patients'))
#now, you can check query:

if not query  :
    print("Sorry, the last name you entered does not match any patients "
      "in the hospital.") #if there are no results this is printed
else:
   for val in [' '.join(i) for i in query]:
     print "\n\t{}".format(val)
```

Comment: I was prompted with the same error saying, looking for a string type when none type was found.